# SQL Query conditions

Tags: sql, r

I have a table with around 90 columns but only three of which I an interested in. Let's call them *code, date1 and date2*; code has integer values 1 to 7 and `date1` and `date2` are standard format dates (`YYYY-MM-DD`).

I need to take all rows with *code* 3, 4 and 5 and rows in which *code* is 1 or 2 and *date1* is not the same as *date2*.

How can I run this query?

I'm using RStudio's `RODBC` package. I know I can just use `R`'s `rbind function` on two separate queries but I would prefer to avoid this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select code,date1,date2
from your_table
where code in (3,4,5)
or (code in (1,2) and date1 != date2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Us an `in` for the codes, then use an `or` for the special condition

```
select *
from MyTable
where code in (3,4,5)
or (code in (1,2) and date1 <> date2)
```